How to set the band description of a multiband image using ArchGDAL.jl
I am trying to use the ArchGDAL.jl API to set the band descriptions for an image of N bands. For example, I have a hyperspectral image, call it mydata, that is taken at 200 wavelengths, and I would like to set the description of each band to be the wavelength that it shows. I have previous experience using the GDAL API for python, and this operation is as simple as (for example):
with gdal.GetDriverByName('ENVI').Create(path,*image_shape,eType=7) as ds:
    ds.WriteArray(mydata)
    for i in range(1,mydata.shape[0]+1,1): #Looping over the 200 bands
        rb = ds.GetRasterBand(i)
        rb.SetDescription("my description")

My problem is, as far as I can tell by looking at the documentation, this "SetDescription" functionality is non-existent in the ArchGDAL.jl API. If someone could guide me to how I can do this using ArchGDAL.jl or suggest another method for accomplishing this task, that would be greatly appreciated!
Here is currently what I am trying to do. See the commented line within the loop.
ds = AG.create(save_path,
            driver = AG.getdriver("ENVI"), 
            width = size(data)[1],
            height = size(data)[2],
            nbands = 1,
            dtype = Float64
        ) do ds
        
            for i in 1:size(mydata)[3] #Looping over the 200 bands
                AG.write!(ds,mydata[:,:,i],i)
                #Here would be great to have some kind of AG.SetDescription(ds,i, "mydescription")
            end
        end

